# Trouble applying the logic of grabbing links from next pages within my current implementation

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, promise

I've created a script in node to scrape the links of different posts from a webpage. The script seems to be working in the right way. Now, I wish to capture the links of different posts from next pages also.

As I'm new to write code in node, I just don't find any idea how I can apply the logic of grabbing links from next pages within my current implementation.

```
const request = require('request');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');

const link = 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-scraping';
const items = [];

let getLinks = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        request(link, function(error, response, html) {
            let $ = cheerio.load(html);
            if (error) return reject(error);
            try {
                $('.summary > h3 > a.question-hyperlink').each(function() {
                    items.push(base_link + $(this).attr("href"));
                });
                resolve(items);
            } catch (e) {
                reject(e);
            }
        });
    });
};

getLinks().then(resultList => {
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < resultList.length; i++) { 
        console.log(resultList[i]);
    }
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```js
const request = require('request');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');

const base_url = 'https://stackoverflow.com';
let requestURL = 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-scraping';
let pageLimit = 5;

(async function main() {
  while (pageLimit-- && requestURL) {
    console.log(`----- current: ${requestURL}, remains: ${pageLimit}`);

    const result = await getLinks(requestURL);

    for (const link of result.links) {
        console.log(link);
    }

    requestURL = result.nextPageURL;
  }
})().catch(console.error);

function getLinks(link) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        request(link, function(error, response, html) {
            if (error) return reject(error);
            let $ = cheerio.load(html);
            const links = [];
            try {
                $('.summary > h3 > a.question-hyperlink').each(function() {
                    links.push(base_url + $(this).attr('href'));
                });
                const nextPageURL = base_url + $('a[rel="next"]').attr('href');
                resolve({ links, nextPageURL });
            } catch (e) {
                reject(e);
            }
        });
    });
};
```

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I wished to achieve. Thanks a lot for your amazing solution.

Comment: It would be very nice if you could clarify in one line in comment what eaxctly this sign ***--*** and this ***&&*** are doing here `while (pageLimit-- && requestURL) `. Sorry for my ignorance.

Comment: @MITHU Here we check 2 conditions at the same time: if we exhaust the page limit and if there is a next page in the pagination. `&&` just joins this 2 conditions (see [Logical AND (&&)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_AND)). `pageLimit--` returns the remainder of the page limit and decrease it by one in each iteration (see [Decrement (--)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Decrement))